# Order model objects by properties of nullable child objects in QueryDSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

My requirement is to retrieve all image (WAHImage) objects whether the specimen (SpecimenImpl) is null or not, whether the taxon name (WACensusImpl) is null or not, and ordering the result by specimen name or taxon name, if available, and displaying the image objects with a null specimen and a null taxon name first.

Using the code below, I get an error `No property coalesce(wAHimage found for type WAHImage`.

It is pretty clear that my use case is [not (yet) fully supported in QueryDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20287194/2495717), namely the ability to query for an entity and order the resulting objects by properties of its nullable child objects. This is because QueryDSL uses CROSS JOINs rather than LEFT JOINs, and you can't order by child object properties with a CROSS JOIN. This seems to be the source of my frustration, and I'm now looking around for other solutions, rather than sticking with QueryDSL.

Spring Data JPA Repository:

```
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<WAHImage, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<WAHImage> {
    Page<WAHImage> findAllByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted, Pageable page);
}
```

Spring Boot (1.5.1) Service, which has ImageRepository autowired in its constructor:

```
@Service
public class ImageService {
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;
    public Page<WAHImage> get(Pageable pageable) {
        return imageRepository.findAllByIsDeleted(false, ImagePredicates.orderByName(pageable));
    }
```

ImagePredicates.orderByName(Pageable):

```
static QPageRequest orderByName(Pageable page) {

    QWAHImage image = QWAHImage.wAHImage;
    QWACensusImpl name = image.census;
    QSpecimenImpl specimen = image.specimen;
    OrderSpecifier genus = name.name1.coalesce(specimen.genus).asc();
    OrderSpecifier species = name.name2.coalesce(specimen.species).asc();
    OrderSpecifier rank = name.rank4.coalesce(
            name.rank3.coalesce(specimen.rank)).asc();
    OrderSpecifier infraspecies = name.name4.coalesce(
            name.name3.coalesce(specimen.infraspecies)).asc();

    OrderSpecifier[] sort = new OrderSpecifier[] {
            genus, species, rank, infraspecies
    };

    return new QPageRequest(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize(), sort);
}
```

---

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ImageController {
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String list(Pageable pageable, Model model) {
        Page<WAHImage> searchResult = imageService.get(pageable);
    }
}
```

---

The error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property coalesce(wAHImage found for type WAHImage!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:542)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:496)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:143)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:144)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:79)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.findAllByIsDeleted(Unknown Source)
at x.y.z.image.ImageService.get(ImageService.java:120)
at x.y.z.image.ImageService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d3a7999.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
at x.y.z.image.ImageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21037cfe.get(<generated>)
at x.y.z.controller.image.ImageController.list(ImageController.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
```

---

Relevant parts of WAHImage model class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class WAHImage extends PersistentImpl {
    private WACensusImpl census = new WACensusImpl();
    private SpecimenImpl specimen = new SpecimenImpl();
    private boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "census_id", nullable = true)
    public WACensusImpl getCensus() {
        return census;
    }

    public void setCensus(WACensusImpl census) {
        this.census = census;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "specimen_id", nullable = true)
    public SpecimenImpl getSpecimen() {
        return specimen;
    }

    public void setSpecimen(SpecimenImpl specimen) {
        this.specimen = specimen;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    public boolean getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

}
```

---

Relevant parts of QWAHImage QueryDSL class.

```
/**
 * QWAHImage is a Querydsl query type for WAHImage
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QWAHImage extends EntityPathBase<WAHImage> {

    public static final QWAHImage wAHImage = new QWAHImage("wAHImage");

    public final x.y.z.db.impl.QPersistentImpl _super = new x.y.z.db.impl.QPersistentImpl(this);

    public final x.y.z.reference.census.impl.QWACensusImpl census;

    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Long> id = _super.id;

    public final BooleanPath isDeleted = createBoolean("isDeleted");

    public final x.y.z.reference.specimen.impl.QSpecimenImpl specimen;
}
```

---

Relevant parts of QWACensusImpl:

```
/**
 * QWACensusImpl is a Querydsl query type for WACensusImpl
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QWACensusImpl extends EntityPathBase<WACensusImpl> {

    public static final QWACensusImpl wACensusImpl = new QWACensusImpl("wACensusImpl");

    public final x.y.z.db.impl.QPersistentWithIDImpl _super = new x.y.z.db.impl.QPersistentWithIDImpl(this);

    //inherited
    public final NumberPath<Long> id = _super.id;

    public final StringPath name1 = createString("name1");

    public final StringPath name2 = createString("name2");

    public final StringPath name3 = createString("name3");

    public final StringPath name4 = createString("name4");

    // extraneous parts omitted.
}
```

Comment: please expose your `Pageable` model and `findAllByIsDeleted(...)` method implementation.

Comment: The `Pageable` is a standard `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` provided to my `ImageController` by Spring, it is usually a Spring `PageRequest` instance. `ImageRepository` is a [Spring Data JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts), which is an implementation by design, Spring Data generates a concrete class for this automatically.

Comment: put the full entity code and also for QWACensusImpl  entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive background research, it appears that my use case has [a long history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272738/hql-order-by-property-of-nullable-property) and remains a [common one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077155/left-join-with-spring-data-jpa-and-querydsl).

To fix this, I could (a) [get access to the EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606905/how-to-access-spring-data-configured-entity-manager-factory-in-custom-implemen) in [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.misc.jpa-context) and from there build the query with [`LEFT JOIN`s](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration), after that I should be able to use the `COALESCE` keyword in `ImagePredicates.orderByName(Pageable)`.

Alternatively, (and the approach I've decided to use) I use a Spring Data @Query on `ImageRepository.findAllByIsDeleted(boolean, Pageable)`:

```
public interface ImageRepository extends JpaRepository<WAHImage, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<WAHImage> {
    @Query("select i from WAHImage i " +
            "left join i.specimen s " +
            "left join i.census c " +
            "left join i.author a " +
            "left join i.copyright co " +
            "left join i.allowedUse au " +
            "where i.isDeleted = ?1 " +
            "order by coalesce(s.genus, c.name1) asc, " +
            "coalesce(s.species, c.name2) asc, " +
            "coalesce(s.infraspecies, c.name4, c.name3) asc")
    Page<WAHImage> findAllByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted, Pageable page);
}
```